# How to make the input is selected on admin form?

Tags: magento2, admin, xml, forms, dropdown-options

I have a form like this. This is used to save a new custom admin. But I have a problem with showing a value in the store_id field while editing.
[image: form for editing]

While showing this form the store field must be selected. The name of this field is store_id but I have to show the name of the store instead. so I need to make a class for getting the store's name. I can get all the names of the stores and use them for the dropdown list. But after seeing the detail when editing, the store_id field is empty and doesn't even show the store_id or the store_name. However, the store_id can be saved to the database.

This is the part for the store_id field at admin_form.xml

```
<field name="store_id">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Module\Vendor\Model\Select\Source\Store</item>
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="componentType" xsi:type="string">field</item>
            <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Store</item>
            <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
            <item name="source" xsi:type="string">Customer</item>
            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">store_id</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</field>
```

and this is the class for showing the name of the store

```
<?php

class Store extends \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\AbstractSource
{

    /**
     * @var \Vendor\Module\Model\CustomFactory
     */
    private $customFactory;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customerFactory
     */
    public function __construct(\Module\Vendor\Model\ResourceModel\Store\CollectionFactory $customFactory)
    {
        $this->customFactory = $customFactory;
    }

    /**
     * Get all options
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getAllOptions()
    {
        $customCollection = $this->customFactory->create();

        $customCollection->addFieldToFilter('status', 'Active');

        $customCollection->setOrder('store_name', 'ASC');

        $this->_options = [['label' => 'Please select', 'value' => '']];

        foreach ($customCollection as $custom) {
            $this->_options[] = ['label' => $custom->getData('store_name'), 'value' => $custom->getData('id')];
        }
        return $this->_options;
    }

     
}
```

How can I make this field is selected based on the store_id and the selected field shows the store's name?

Comment: In your form dataProvider class, just before return statement, echo your returning data and exit to see if store_id is actually set there or not.

Comment: Thank you so much you are absolutely right that the store_id does not exist in the array for loading the data. so I need to make adjustments to the array. I inject the store factory get the store_id, and insert this store_id to the array like this $this->loadedData[$model->getId()]["store_id"] = $store_id;

Comment: Yes I was going to tell you this, glad that you did it yourself, must be good learning, cheers! Still answering for others to help :)

Comment: Good luck then! it will be very helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because `store_ids` are not from same table as your custom model, so it doesn't get loaded, you need to set in manually, in either `_afterLoad` of your model or `DataProvider` class to set it in array with same `array index` as the field name in your form and you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your `Store` class, it must be implemented from `Magento\Framework\Data\OptionSourceInterface`.

Then replace the `getAllOptions` function with `toOptionArray`, the content of the new function function is

```
public function toOptionArray(): array
    {
        $result = [];

        $customCollection = $this->customFactory->create();
        $customCollection->addFieldToFilter('status', 'Active');
        $customCollection->setOrder('store_name', 'ASC');

        $result[] = [
            'value' => '',
            'label' => 'Please select'
        ];
        
        foreach ($customCollection as $custom) {
            $result[] = [
                'value' => $custom->getData('id'),
                'label' => $custom->getData('store_name')
            ];
        }


        return $result;
    }
```

And you must make sure the column name in your database and the field name in your UI component file is the same `store_id` .

Comment: thank you. I have tried this and the result is the same. The field is not selected. The field name already the same as the field name in the table. I checked the field name by using inspect just want to make sure and the name is store_id;